How to use TL431 as a comparator to switch NPN transistor?
When the voltage at ref pin of TL431 is less than 2.5 V, Vka is 5 V.
When the voltage at ref pin of TL431 is greater than 2.5 V, Vka is 2 V.
How can I turn off the NPN transistor (TIP122)?


Your first two resistors form a potential divider. Does that hint help?

No matter what the voltage is at ref pin, the voltage at Kathode is always greater than 2V. so the npn transistor stays always on. I don't see how to turn it off ? @Neil_UK

I need to pull down the base of npn transistor to ground to turn off. But tl431 doesn't allow this?

It is a bad idea to use a TL431 as a comparator. The part is prone to oscillations and behaviors in this mode depend on the brand. I have seen many failures in production. If you still want to pursue in that direction, you can insert a Zener diode in series with the transistor base to drop 2.7 V for instance (with sufficient current in the knee) but then, add hysteresis to the circuit, especially if the transistor will conduct some current. Otherwise, better resort to a dedicated voltage-monitoring circuit.

@across I need to pull down the base of npn transistor to ground to turn off No you don't. You only need to pull it well below 0.6 V

If you plan on using a TL431, hysteresis is important so that the transition from one state to the other remains swift. Otherwise, risks of oscillations exist. The below circuit is a possible approach with the addition of a small-signal PNP transistor, biasing the TIP122 when the TL431 conducts:

I added diode \$D_1\$ to beef up the bias at \$Q_1\$'s collector a bit but that is perhaps not necessary considering the two \$V_{be}\$ across \$R_3\$. This bias is used to produce hysteresis on the TL431 via \$R_8\$ so that it stays the least amount of time in high-gain linear mode. As \$Q_1\$ is blocked when \$V_{in}\$ is below the input threshold, diode \$D_2\$ can probably be omitted.
As I said in the comment section, I am not a fan of using the TL431 as a comparator and there are dedicated ICs for this function. If you want to tinker a circuit for trying, then the one I proposed seems ok on simulation.

You don't.  Not as shown, anyway.  This is indeed a problem!
Note that TL431 is better described as an open-collector op-amp with conspicuously large (but well-defined) VOS; or a sort of "ideal BJT" with very high hFE, suspiciously low fT, and conspicuously stable VBE.  It also has diodes between all three terminals: as such, it is impossible for the output (K) to pull farther than VF below input (REF).  This determines the saturation voltage, and indeed is around 2V as you have noted.
You could apply a base voltage divider:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(Voltage sources (left) represent TL431 with pull-up.)
But, this is tricky because the on/off ratio isn't very high (check the simulation), and it's still very sensitive to temperature (Q1 VBE has a strong negative temperature coefficient).
A Darlington transistor needs VBE(off) below 0.5V or so, to ensure both transistors are properly "off".
One solution would be to use a much higher supply voltage, say 10 or 15V instead of 5.  Then, the on/off ratio is larger, and the base divider has something to work with.
Otherwise, better to use a device that can deliver a wider voltage swing, or switch properly as such:

Consider TLV431, having a 1.24V threshold.  It has the same diodes between terminals as TL431, so saturation is down to ~0.6V.  This still isn't enough directly, but the wider swing allows the base divider to finish the job.
Combination comparator with reference, e.g. LT6703, TLV3011B, etc. The output may be stronger (saturating towards GND), CMOS type, faster, etc., and hysteresis may be available standard (without having to wire the TL(V)431 for it).

Mind, you don't mention if hysteresis is necessary (or if you're aware that there are concerns to be addressed with it), so I've not gone into detail on this aspect, but I would be remiss not to mention it at all.
Brief testing of TLV431CLPE3 shows that, in fact the REF-K diode is not simply a diode, but almost any current forward-biasing it causes the device to shut down (causing oscillation, both pin voltages rising), presumably due to current injection into a more limited circuit (i.e., they show the same ref-opamp-BJT equivalent circuit as the TL431, but this is only equivalent in normal operation).  I would not recommend using this device for comparator service.

The load can go on/off briefly, no issue.. . hysteresis isn't a big concern here. I'm looking for a simple circuit that connects load when the input reaches a threshold.  Thank you so much for confirming that the tl431 can't switch off an npn transistor. I'll change to pnp transistor and do high side switching..
